# Meta tags prerender Angular 9 don't appear

Tags: angular, metadata, meta-tags, server-side-rendering, prerender

I updated my Angular application with Angular 9.

I add the Server Side Rendering and I compile my application to enable prerender with

```
ng run my-app:prerender
```

I add in **server.ts** the line

```
import "reflect-metadata";
```

I see the meta tags inside my pages above "index.html" files.

But when I go directly on my pages without "index.html" I can't see the meta tags with prerender.

How can I add meta tags on my pages like "https://www.mywebsite.com/page/" as **index.html** pages generated by prerendering like https://www.mywebsite.com/page/index.html ?

Finally when I check my page with twitter card verificator I can see metadata on https://www.mywebsite.com/page/index.html but not on https://www.mywebsite.com/page/.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem ! It provide from Amazon Web Service.

Indeed I was hosting my application as an Angular SPA on AWS S3 and Cloud Front. However Cloud Front systematically redirects to the basic index.html thus always generating the same meta tags. I followed this page https://stevepapa.com/how-to-specify-a-default-root-object-for-static-website-subdirectories-on-aws-cloudfront/ and it was good.